# Alternative for cansnippet?

Tags: software-development

I am looking for an alternative for cansnippet https://www.cansnippet.com/ The awesomeness of this tool is that with a shortcut I can search (in a spotlight looking box) and paste the snippet I'm looking for in the foreground application like in terminal.

One of the drawbacks is not sync or backup capability.

Requirements:

- Should be able to search and insert snippet in any app without leaving app.
- Manage code snippets.
- Store snippet from selecting a snippet from any other ap and pressing a shortcut
- Back up

**Env:** MacOS

Can be up to 30$

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: done.. Added requirements.

Comment: Thanks, much better already! Just two questions remain: What OS should it run on? Must it be [tag:gratis] – or, in case of paid solutions, how much you'd be willing to spend?

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/cansnippet/?platform=mac

Comment: Nope.. Please read my requirements